# Shortcut to switch between Themes in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, shortcuts

Sometimes I need to switch between a theme that I created and the default theme in Notepad++.

Is there a shortcut to perform this action, rather than going through the menu:

> Settings > Style Configurator > Select Theme?

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Settings > Shortcut Mapper` and down toward the bottom is Style Configuration.  You can set your shortcut key and then switch.    That's about the only way to really do it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Travis points out, there doesn't appear to be a shortcut for changing themes. You can do it in AutoHotkey though, by copy-pasting the following into its configuration file:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad++
    !1::SendInput {ALT}ts{ENTER}{HOME}s{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}
    !2::SendInput {ALT}ts{ENTER}{HOME}ss{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}
#IfWinActive
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> changes the theme to "Solarized Light," and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to "Solarized."

Explained:

1. `#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad++` makes sure the shortcuts only trigger while Notepad++ is the active window, so as not to have unexpected behavior while other windows are active.
2. `!1::` defines an action for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. `!` stands for <kbd>Alt</kbd>, `^` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, `+` for <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and `#` for <kbd>Win</kbd>. They can be combined (order insignificant) like this: `^+k::` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>.
3. `{ALT}t` brings up the "Settings" menu.
4. `s{ENTER}` selects "Style Configurator..."
5. `{HOME}` resets the selected theme to the top item (so as to always count from the top).
6. `s` or `ss` selects themes by cycling through by starting letters. You can also use a bunch of `{DOWN}`s, but that's more prone to breaking when styles are added or removed from the list.
7. `{TAB}` seven times brings us to <kbd>Save and Close</kbd>, after which we hit `{ENTER}`.

**This solution was created for Notepad++ 6.6.3. If it doesn't work for the version of Notepad++ you're running, most likely some items were added to the "Style Configurator" menu such that more or less tabs are needed to get to <kbd>Save and Close</kbd>.**